# How much recording time at 1080p30 on a 32GB card on a GoPro Hero (1)?

Tags: video-recording, sd-card

Is there a generic data recording rate for the different capture options on GoPro Heroes?

I'm trying to determine what size of SD card I should buy for my GoPro and I'd like to get an approximation. Is there a grid somewhere that details this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you try to go to the product web site and check?
http://gopro.com/support/articles/recording-time-in-each-video-setting

I know it is about Hero2, but i think the values will not change much. Be aware fully charged battery will power the camera for no more than 3 hours

Comment: Nice, I missed it because I was looking at the original Hero product page. I'm aware of the battery life :)